# looking to loop for 2 element in the same time (php /xpath )

Tags: php, loops, curl, xpath, foreach

I'm trying to extract 2 elements using  PHP Curl and Xpath!

So far have the element separated in `foreach` but I would like to have them in the same time:

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->evaluate("//p[@class='row']/a/@href");
//$elements = $xpath->query("//p[@class='row']/a");

foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $url = $element->nodeValue;
    //$title = $element->nodeValue;    
}
```

When I `echo` each one out of the `foreach` I only get 1 element and when its echoed inside the `foreach` i get all of them.

My question is how can I get them both at the same time (url and title ) and whats the best way to add them into myqsl using pdo.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need, in this case, to use XPath twice. You could do one query and navigate to the associated other node(s).

For example, find all of the `href`s that you are interested in and get their `ownerElement`'s (the `<a>`) node value.

```
$hrefs = $xpath->query("//p[@class='row']/a/@href");
foreach ($hrefs as $href) {
    $url = $href->value;
    $title = $href->ownerElement->nodeValue;
    // Insert into db here
}
```

Or, find all of the `<a>`s that you are interested in and get their `href` attributes.

```
$anchors = $xpath->query("//p[@class='row']/a[@href]");
foreach ($anchors as $anchor) {
    $url = $anchor->getAttribute("href");
    $title = $anchor->nodeValue;
    // Insert into db here
}
```

Comment: that worked great , thanks a lot , could you provide me with some reference where i can expand my xpath knowledge please ! thanks again .

Comment: A good starting point is Schlitt's [XPath Overview](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html).

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `$url` on each iteration. Maybe use an array?

```
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->evaluate("//p[@class='row']/a/@href");
//$elements = $xpath->query("//p[@class='row']/a");

$urls = array();

foreach ($elements as $element){
    array_push($urls, $element->nodeValue);
    //$title = $element->nodeValue;

}
```

Comment: its not working ! what i want to do is get thetitle and  the url of the same element as the query for each one that i put on my code is working perfectly fine , just looking for a simple way to get both and insert them in db !